# Needing guidance on image preview for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, preview

Hey guys I am needing some guidance on what this kind of image feature is called. I tried googling around but cant seem to find the correct name of the image feature. Its where there a bunch of small images surround a bigger image and when a smaller image is selected or hovered over then it will be shown on the bigger image place as seen here.

[image]

I am trying to add this feature into a clients website in wordpress but dont know the correct term to look for or if a plugin exists that allows me to do this sort of thing in wordpress.

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Well I guess that would be called a [photo gallery with thumbnails](https://www.google.es/search?q=photo+gallery+with+thumbnails) or something like that.

Comment: Ah thanks ill try googling that to see what I can find. :) Thank you!

Comment: The Woocommerce plugin now has this built into the product gallery if you're selling products online. You can also use Slick Carousel slider syncing. I suspect Owl Carousel has something similar.

Comment: My client is not selling things just displaying a item and listing its specs :). I didnt find any luck with any of the ones you suggested does anyone have any more suggestions? Thanks so much for your input so far :)